# How to display multiple plots with captions?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am supposed to make a checkbox app that with each checkbox displaying a different plot with a caption.  I want a decomposition plot, gg season plot and a acf plot for each button.  I have the basic code for checkbox's however I don't know where to input the plot code so that it will show up when a box is selected.  Any information regarding Renderplot or plotoutput within a checkbox app will be very helpful thank you.

Comment: Greetings! Can you show what you have done so far? It would be instructive to see what you have already accomplished and what you are expecting. Otherwise it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your `radioButtons` value to render the correct plot in the `renderPlot`:

```
library(shiny)

ui = function(){
  fluidPage(
    radioButtons( "type", "", c( "plot", "hist" )),
    plotOutput( "plot" ))
}

server = function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req( input$type ) # Plot type required

    if( input$type == "plot" )
      plot( rnorm( 100 ) )
    else
      hist( rnorm( 100 ) )
  })
}

shinyApp( ui, server )
```